# Why A→B∉Γ implies Γ∪{A}$\not\vdash$B

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

The setting is intuitionistic propositional logic. Γ is a consistent disjunctive(A∨B∈Γ⇒A∈Γ or B∈Γ) theory. I can't figure out why the claim stated in the title is correct. Let Γ be the smallest consistent disjunctive theory which contains p→(p→q). Then p∉Γ,p→q∉Γ but Γ∪{p}⊢p→q so Γ∪{p}⊢q. If the claim in title is right then my reasoning must be wrong but I can't see why.

The picture below is the original problem, if it helps.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$, then by $\to$-intro :

> $\Gamma \vdash A \to B$.

But $\Gamma$ is *regular*, and thus closed, and so : $A \to B \in \Gamma$ : contradiction.